# How to Access Next Row Values from data source in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

My result is like that:
[image: My Result]
i want Something like that
[image]

like in Given Table, for Column CAT if Next field value is same then i want to supress  that field in jasper report

Comment: What is the datasource you are using for the report?

Comment: i have used JRBeanCollectionDataSource in report

Comment: Do you want to print the value in `CAT` only once?

Comment: No, i want check the next value and current value if it is equal then hide current value and please ref screenshots. (only compare next row value)

Comment: What if there are three records for `CAT=A`?

Comment: only check the next row value, no need to check the third or more row values

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132679/discussion-between-pravin-netke-and-viki888).